# How do I replace a value taking into account the previous value from a list in R?

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, apply, mapply

I am trying to replace all the ones values after zero with zero values.

The list is something like this:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1)
```

So, the next value after 0 are also 0.

I have done it with loops but because it´s a large amount of information is a lot of time to wait.
I hope someone could give me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x[ c(FALSE, x[-length(x)] == 0) ] <- 0
x
#  [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
identical(
  x,
  c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1) # from the OP
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: It seems to me that I posted a rather similar solution to yours. If you wish, then I can remove it :)

Comment: I think they're similar enough, I don't mind. Yours is slightly different, and while I can't think of a time where `which(.)` would be functionally more or less resilient to something in the data, I think they both have some value. Yours wins by code-golf and simplicity/readability, ergo my upvote :-)

Comment: Would you mind elaborate when `which()` wouldn't be functionally resilient?

Comment: In some uses (outside of this `[` use) where a conditional must have non-zero length, then `which(.)` can return length 0. This is the same discussion as `grep` versus `grepl`. But, as I said, I cannot think of a time in this use when `which` would have any different (better or worse) handling/resiliency, so ... it works. They are not identical answers, so I think keeping both has values. I think yours is likely better in many ways.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, it's always great to learn something from more experienced people :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
x[which(x == 0) + 1] <- 0

 [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```